java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: del. Trying to run a JavaFX project
I have to do a project using JavaFX and after following the installation i tried to run the default main but this problem showed up:
Error: impossible finding or loading main class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: del
Running with mac M1
Eclipse Version: 2023-09 (4.29.0)
I tried other versions of JavaFX and move the library form Classpath Entries to Modulepath Entries

See: How do I resolve ClassNotFoundException? Because your error indicates this is your "main class", check your command line used for execution - probably it has spaces in it or in incorrect format or typographic errors causing the main class (last argument on the command line before program arguments) not to be found.  Add the exact command line text executed by you or the IDE and other supporting information to   the question by editing it to make your issue reproducible.

The getting started guide is at openjfx.  Follow it exactly to ensure you can get the simple hello world application provided there to work in your environment.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
